# mysql average latest 5 rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table:

```
describe tests;

+-----------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field     | Type      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-----------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id        | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| line_id   | int(11)   | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| test_time | timestamp | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| alarm_id  | int(11)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| result    | int(11)   | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
+-----------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

And I execute query:

```
SELECT avg(result) FROM tests WHERE line_id = 4 ORDER BY test_time LIMIT 5;
```

which I want to generate average of 5 latest results.
Still something is not ok, because query generates average of all table data.
What can be wrong?

Comment: `AVG` is an aggregate function, it will give you only one value for all the rows, you might need to add a `GROUP BY` to get the `AVG` for each group, but we need to know what is wrong? What are you trying to do. Please post some sample data and the desired output.

Comment: change your sorting of data means ORDER BY id DESC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the *last* five rows, then you need to order by the time column in *descending* order:

```
select avg(result)
from (select result
      from tests
      where line_id = 4
      order by test_time desc
      limit 5
     ) t
```

Comment: Doesn't the `LIMIT` run *before* the `ORDER BY`?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud . . . No.  `limit` runs after the `order by`.

Answer (score 0):

the guy before submitted something link that

for my it works

```
select avg( id ) from ( select id from rand limit 5) as id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Only one result set will be returned because of the AVG function.

Comment: Ok so you don't need to use the limit syntax. BTW the question was asked by @Gordon Linoff. In short you just need to average the output of the sub-query.